# Convert to Ascii. Extended ASCII characters not working. C language

Tags: windows, ascii

Extended 8-bit ASCII characters are not working 
I'm trying to make a table with 
putchar(218); putchar(196); putchar(194); 
Instead of lines or ascii char i get Ĵ and Ŀ.
Everything i've tried was not working.

Comment: Please explain your problem clearly. Currently, your problem is not clear about what your question is and where you are facing the problem

Comment: Please state precisely what the `stdout` stream is. Is this a standard Windows console application that's connected to an instance of the Windows console (i.e. conhost.exe), the new Windows terminal (i.e. openconsole.exe displaying in a wt.exe tab), or an alternative console (e.g. ConEmu wrapping conhost.exe)? Or is this a Cygwin or MSYS2 application that's connected to an emulated pty and a POSIX terminal such as mintty? Is `stdout` redirected to a pipe or disk file? What *exactly* is the respective result for `putchar` when called with 194, 196, and 218?

Comment: @ErykSun input / output. There is not much to explain . Extended ASCII chars are not displayed at all. That L or J is a random combination. I posted a Photo so you can have a look. I have tried with Visual Studio , Codeblocks , both not working.

Answer (score 0):

[input / output. There is not much to explain . Extended ASCII chars are not displayed at all. That L or J is a random combination.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW8P2.jpg)